# Reverse the Fish-eye Distortion(I've used openCV with VC++)

Tags: c, opencv, visual-c++

I've made a simulation of fish eye distortion.
I want to develop a reverse program that can convert the distorted image to normal image.
I've tried to use undistortPonts() function but couldn't understand the input(dist-coefficient).
`cv.UndistortPoints(distorted, undistorted, intrinsics, dist_coeffs)`

My code for fish eye distortion:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>

void sampleImage(const IplImage* arr, float idx0, float idx1, CvScalar& res)
{
    if(idx0<0 || idx1<0 || idx0>(cvGetSize(arr).height-1) || idx1>(cvGetSize(arr).width-1))
    {
        res.val[0]=0;
        res.val[1]=0;
        res.val[2]=0;
        res.val[3]=0;
        return;
    }

    float idx0_fl=floor(idx0);
    float idx0_cl=ceil(idx0);
    float idx1_fl=floor(idx1);
    float idx1_cl=ceil(idx1);

    CvScalar s1=cvGet2D(arr,(int)idx0_fl,(int)idx1_fl);
    CvScalar s2=cvGet2D(arr,(int)idx0_fl,(int)idx1_cl);
    CvScalar s3=cvGet2D(arr,(int)idx0_cl,(int)idx1_cl);
    CvScalar s4=cvGet2D(arr,(int)idx0_cl,(int)idx1_fl);

    float x = idx0 - idx0_fl;
    float y = idx1 - idx1_fl;

    res.val[0]= s1.val[0]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2.val[0]*(1-x)*y + s3.val[0]*x*y + s4.val[0]*x*(1-y);
    res.val[1]= s1.val[1]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2.val[1]*(1-x)*y + s3.val[1]*x*y + s4.val[1]*x*(1-y);
    res.val[2]= s1.val[2]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2.val[2]*(1-x)*y + s3.val[2]*x*y + s4.val[2]*x*(1-y);
    res.val[3]= s1.val[3]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2.val[3]*(1-x)*y + s3.val[3]*x*y + s4.val[3]*x*(1-y);
}

float xscale;
float yscale;
float xshift;
float yshift;
float getRadialX(float x,float y,float cx,float cy,float k)
{
    x = (x*xscale+xshift);
    y = (y*yscale+yshift);
    float res = x+((x-cx)*k*((x-cx)*(x-cx)+(y-cy)*(y-cy)));
    return res;
}

float getRadialY(float x,float y,float cx,float cy,float k)
{
    x = (x*xscale+xshift);
    y = (y*yscale+yshift);
    float res = y+((y-cy)*k*((x-cx)*(x-cx)+(y-cy)*(y-cy)));
    return res;
}

float thresh = 1;
float calc_shift(float x1,float x2,float cx,float k)
{
    float x3 = x1+(x2-x1)*0.5;
    float res1 = x1+((x1-cx)*k*((x1-cx)*(x1-cx)));
    float res3 = x3+((x3-cx)*k*((x3-cx)*(x3-cx)));

    //  std::cerr<<"x1: "<<x1<<" - "<<res1<<" x3: "<<x3<<" - "<<res3<<std::endl;

    if(res1>-thresh && res1 < thresh)
    return x1;
    if(res3<0)
    {
        return calc_shift(x3,x2,cx,k);
    }
    else
    {
        return calc_shift(x1,x3,cx,k);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    IplImage* src = cvLoadImage( "D:\\2012 Projects\\FishEye\\Debug\\images\\grid1.bmp", 1 );
    IplImage* dst = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(src),src->depth,src->nChannels);
    IplImage* dst2 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(src),src->depth,src->nChannels);
    float K=0.002;
    float centerX=(float)(src->width/2);
    float centerY=(float)(src->height/2);
    int width = cvGetSize(src).width;
    int height = cvGetSize(src).height;

    xshift = calc_shift(0,centerX-1,centerX,K);
    float newcenterX = width-centerX;
    float xshift_2 = calc_shift(0,newcenterX-1,newcenterX,K);

    yshift = calc_shift(0,centerY-1,centerY,K);
    float newcenterY = height-centerY;
    float yshift_2 = calc_shift(0,newcenterY-1,newcenterY,K);
    //  scale = (centerX-xshift)/centerX;
    xscale = (width-xshift-xshift_2)/width;
    yscale = (height-yshift-yshift_2)/height;

    std::cerr<<xshift<<" "<<yshift<<" "<<xscale<<" "<<yscale<<std::endl;
    std::cerr<<cvGetSize(src).height<<std::endl;
    std::cerr<<cvGetSize(src).width<<std::endl;

    for(int j=0;j<cvGetSize(dst).height;j++)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<cvGetSize(dst).width;i++)
        {
            CvScalar s;
            float x = getRadialX((float)i,(float)j,centerX,centerY,K);
            float y = getRadialY((float)i,(float)j,centerX,centerY,K);
            sampleImage(src,y,x,s);
            cvSet2D(dst,j,i,s);
        }
    }


    #if 0
    cvNamedWindow( "Source1", 1 );
    cvShowImage( "Source1", dst);
    cvWaitKey(0);
    #endif

    cvSaveImage("D:\\2012 Projects\\FishEye\\Debug\\images\\grid3.bmp",dst,0);

    cvNamedWindow( "Source1", 1 );
    cvShowImage( "Source1", src);
    cvWaitKey(0);

    cvNamedWindow( "Distortion", 2 );
    cvShowImage( "Distortion", dst);
    cvWaitKey(0);

    #if 0
    for(int j=0;j<cvGetSize(src).height;j++)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<cvGetSize(src).width;i++)
        {
            CvScalar s;
            sampleImage(src,j+0.25,i+0.25,s);
            cvSet2D(dst,j,i,s);
        }
    }

    cvNamedWindow( "Source1", 1 );
    cvShowImage( "Source1", src);
    cvWaitKey(0);

    #endif  

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, my original anwser was about the undistortion algorithm for individual points. If you want to undistort a complete image, there is a much simpler technique, as explained in this other thread:

[Understanding of openCV undistortion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21958521/understanding-of-opencv-undistortion)

The outline of the algorithm (which is the one used in OpenCV function `undistort()`) is as follow. For each pixel of the destination lens-corrected image do:

- Convert the pixel coordinates `(u_dst, v_dst)` to normalized coordinates `(x', y')` using the inverse of the calibration matrix `K`,
- Apply your lens-distortion model, to obtain the distorted normalized coordinates `(x'', y'')`,
- Convert `(x'', y'')` to distorted pixel coordinates `(u_src, v_src)` using the calibration matrix `K`,
- Use the interpolation method of your choice to find the intensity/depth associated with the pixel coordinates `(u_src, v_src)` in the source image, and assign this intensity/depth to the current destination pixel `(u_dst, v_dst)`.

---

**Original answer:**

Here is the undistortion algorithm extracted from OpenCV function `undistortPoints()` :

```
void dist2norm(const cv::Point2d &pt_dist, cv::Point2d &pt_norm) const {

    pt_norm.x = (pt_dist.x-Kcx)/Kfx;
    pt_norm.y = (pt_dist.y-Kcy)/Kfy;

    int niters=(Dk1!=0.?5:0);
    double x0=pt_norm.x, y0=pt_norm.y;
    for(int i=0; i<niters; ++i) {

        double x2=pt_norm.x*pt_norm.x,
            y2=pt_norm.y*pt_norm.y,
            xy=pt_norm.x*pt_norm.y,
            r2=x2+y2;

        double icdist = 1./(1 + ((Dk3*r2 + Dk2)*r2 + Dk1)*r2);
        double deltaX = 2*Dp1*xy + Dp2*(r2 + 2*x2);
        double deltaY = Dp1*(r2 + 2*y2) + 2*Dp2*xy;

        pt_norm.x = (x0-deltaX)*icdist;
        pt_norm.y = (y0-deltaY)*icdist;
    }
}
```

If you provide the coordinates of a point in the distorted image in argument `pt_dist`, it will calculate the normalized coordinates of the associated point and return them in `pt_norm`. Then, you can obtain the coordinates of the associated point in the undistorted image as

```
pt_undist = K . [pt_norm.x; pt_norm.y; 1]
```

where K is the camera matrix.

The standard lens distortion model used by OpenCV is explained at the beginning of [this page](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html):

[image: Distortion model equations]

where the distortion coefficients are `(k1,k2,p1,p2,k3, k4,k5,k6)` (most often we use `k4=k5=k6=0`).

I don't know what is your model for FishEye distortion, but you can surely adapt the above algorithm to your case. Otherwise, you may use a non-linear optimization algorithm (e.g. Levenberg-Marquardt or any other), to recover the undistorted coordinates from the distorted one.

Comment: that's the Brown model. For FishEye distortion, refer to Luber model

Comment: @blackibiza this was just to show how this is done in OpenCV for the Brown model, then he can adapt the same algorithm to his model. Anyway, there is a much simpler algorithm, as mentioned in my edit.