# What numerical iterative algorithm is actually used in cv::undistortPoints()?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, numerical-methods, distortion

This question relates to the numerical method used in undistortPoints in openCV and was asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31184972/opencv-cvundistortpoints-iterative-algorithm-explanation):

I have an additional question. One of the answers states that undistortPoints in opencv uses the method of false position. However that is not obvious to me.

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_position_method), the double false position method needs two guesses. The code doesn't show 2 guesses being taken but rather only one guess is used.

I have also struggled to find anything written on false position methods with more than one variable.

Any references to help me clarify how the method used is infact a false position method would be appreciated.

The original opencv code can be found [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/calib3d/src/undistort.cpp#L371)

Comment: Isn't it rather a fixed-point method ?

Comment: Please change the title to reference the question inside your post.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, it is the [Jacobi method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_method) being applied to a set of nonlinear equations.

A summarized version of the OpenCV algorithm reimplemented in python might help the explanation (notice that it is only using distortion parameters k1-k6, p1, p2 for brevity):

```py
def undistort(u, v):
    x = (u - cx) / fx
    y = (v - cy) / fy

    x0 = x
    y0 = y

    for _ in range(5):
      r2 = x * x + y * y
      icdist = (1 + ((k6 * r2 + k5) * r2 + k4) * r2) / (1 + ((k3 * r2 + k2) * r2 + k1) * r2)
      assert icdist > 0, f"{icdist=} <= 0"
      delta_x = 2 * p1 * x * y + p2 * (r2 + 2 * x * x)
      delta_y = p1 * (r2 + 2 * y * y) + 2 * p2 * x * y
      x = (x0 - delta_x) * icdist
      y = (y0 - delta_y) * icdist

    return x, y
```

Do not get confused as to what `x0` and `y0` are. They are not working as guesses for the Jacobi method, they are just constants `(u - cx) / fx` and `(v - cy) / fy`, they do not depend on `x` nor `y`. Having said that the expression `x = (x0 - delta_x) * icdist` (and the equivalent for `y`) is just what you get once you solve symbolically the [calibration equations](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#details) for `x`, and thus that gets used for the Jacobi iterations.

As to why this works in a nonlinear set of equations, check [this answer](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/34448/42093). Basically, the method usually works on "nice" non-linear functions.